# why this insert gives syntax error

Tags: c++, sql

```
res = PQexec(conn,"INSERT INTO worker (fullname,type) VALUES ('"ptr"',"type")");
```

`type` is integer and `ptr` is string. What is the problem here? How can I fix it? Is there a problem with "" is

Comment: why is this `type` in double quotes?

Comment: i dont know how it is formatted, Type is integer how can i do it?

Comment: You probably should use query parameters instead of string concatenation in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
res = PQexec(conn,"INSERT INTO worker (fullname,type) VALUES ('"ptr"',"type")");
```

use a stringstream to create the string

```
#include <sstream>
std::stringstream ss;

ss << "INSERT INTO worker (fullname,type) VALUES ('" << ptr << "'," << type << ")";
res = PQexec(conn, ss.str().c_str() );
```

Comment: Be careful though, this is open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: true, but he should then use some kind of prepare mechanism to set up arguments but I am just helping with his question.

Comment: That mechanism is already apart of PQexec, documentation is here:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-exec.html

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't automatically convert values to strings. To build a string, use `std::stringstream` as illustrated in claptrap's answer.

However, unless you can be completely sure that the variables are secure against injection attacks, you would be much better off passing the values as parameters rather than injecting them directly into the SQL, something like:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << type;
std::string type_string = ss.str();  // or std::to_string(type) if available

const char * values[] = {ptr, type_string.c_str()};

res = PQexecParams(conn, "INSERT INTO worker (fullname,type) VALUES ($1,$2)",
    2, NULL, values, NULL, NULL, 0);
```